# implementin log system in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to integrate a log file to my website which I made with symfony2.
I mean I want to save every action of the user :clicks button, saving requests to database
Is that possible?

Does anybody have an idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

### Logging in Symfony 2

Yes, this is actually described in the documentation:

- [Symfony 2: Cookbook: How to use Monolog to write Logs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/logging/monolog.html)

One of the examples includes this:

> To log a message simply get the logger service from the container in
>   your controller:
>
> ```
> public function indexAction()
> {
>     $logger = $this->get('logger');
>     $logger->info('I just got the logger');
>     $logger->err('An error occurred');
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```

Just create an AJAX action called separately from client side (if this is what you wanted), or create a "wrapper" around your AJAX calls (if this is what you wanted instead). It all depends on what you really want. Good luck!

### More about Monolog and saving to files

The `Monolog` has also separate documentation here:

- https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/README.mdown

The handlers that you may be interested in are: `StreamHandler` ("*Logs records into any PHP stream, use this for log files*") and/or `RotatingFileHandler` ("*Logs records to a file and creates one logfile per day. It will also delete files older than `$maxFiles`. You should use `logrotate` for high profile setups though, this is just meant as a quick and dirty solution*").

Comment: could u plz give me a clear tutorial about that. the documentation is not clear for me. I am still a biginner in that. @Tadeck.

Comment: @user2269869: I am sorry, I cannot give that, but I can answer your questions. You should explain in detail what exactly causes problems for you. In other words: [WhatHaveYouTried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com) or [find someone who can spend the time on solving your issues](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). Good luck anyway. Let me know, if you have some specific questions.

Comment: I just added the code above in an action of my controller. but I don't know where to find the output. I don't know also if I have some packages to download. It is not clear for me. @Tadeck

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/index.html)