# adding monolog to website symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to usemonolog in my symfony website.

Actually I added these lines to an action of my controller in order to save every actions that occurs ie clicks on buttons, database changing ...

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $logger = $this->get('logger');
    $logger->info('I just got the logger');
    $logger->err('An error occurred');

    // ...
}

but I don't know where to find the output and how even to make the first steps with monolog.
```

Could anybody help me plz?

Comment: should I add something to the file config.yml in order to import a package or something else?

Comment: the page is not found @DonCallisto

Comment: @DonCallisto means http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410811/implementin-log-system-in-symfony2

Comment: [RTFM!](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This will log message in the log files:

```
app/logs/prod.log
app/logs/dev.log
```

Basicly: app/logs/your_environment.log